# Form Input Radio Doesn't Go To The Request Object Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, eloquent

I have a form that contains gender input in the form of a radio button, but when I try to submit with an empty value, the radio button element doesn't get into the Request object which in the example below the input name is jenis_kelamin. But if jenis_kelamin has a value, then the jenis_kelamin element will be entered into the Request Object.

I need the element in the Request object because if the radio element is empty, there will be an error with the input message required. So, what I'm hoping for is how the radio input gets into the Request object when the value is empty and why this is happening.

```
Routes

Route::get('/mahasiswas/create', 'MahasiswaController@create')->name('mahasiswas.create');
Route::post('/mahasiswas', 'MahasiswaController@store')->name('mahasiswas.store');

Controller

public function create(){
  return view('form-pendaftaran');
}
public function store(Request $request){
   dump($request);
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{route('mahasiswas.store')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Jenis Kelamin</label>
   <input type="radio" name="jenis_kelamin" id="laki-laki" value="L">
   <label for="laki-laki">Laki-laki</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Daftar</button>
</form>
```

Radio Input if the value is null

[image: Radio Input if the value is null]

Radio Input if there a value

[image: Radio Input if there a value]

Notes : I'm using Laravel 7

Comment: If you don't select a radio option, nothing is sent to the server. In Laravel, this is OK; `required` validation will work for missing fields.

Comment: No, when the radio input is empty there will be no error message required, As I mentioned above, how can I access @error ('jenis_kelamin') while the radio input is not in the Request Object, I have tried it.

Comment: Yes, it will; the rule `'jenis_kelamin' => 'required'` inside your validation will trigger an error if the field is missing, then `$errors->has('jenis_kelamin')` will be `true`, and `$errors->first('jenis_kelamin')` will be `'The jenis kelamin field is required'`. Include the validation you're using in the question, and how you're outputting the error.

Comment: @TimLewis is right, if you have a "required" rule on the `jenis_kelamin` field and that filed id not sent, itll fail validation and the error will be present on the response

Comment: Hmm, last night I tried what I mentioned but the results still couldn't without clear reasons, but now the message required is displayed. Thank you all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by putting a hidden input with the same name before the radio inputs

```
<form action="{{route('mahasiswas.store')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Jenis Kelamin</label>
   <input type="hidden" name="jenis_kelamin" value="" />
   <input type="radio" name="jenis_kelamin" id="laki-laki" value="L">
   <label for="laki-laki">Laki-laki</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Daftar</button>
</form>
```

If the user checks the radio input, then it will override the hidden input you set.

PS: The same fix applies for checkboxes too

PPS: Probably the fix written in the comments works too, but this one works regardless of the framework used

PPPS: This fix may become a problem if a query selection by the name attribute is done, but the developer must be aware of that.